# Additional line breaks adding to my codes by hosting

Tags: php, formatting

This is happening to me most of the time. When I upload my files to host and when I get try to edit them back, host add line breaks to all rows (returns to every line)

When I upload

```
line one
line two
line three
```

and when try to edit I see

```
line one

line two

line three
```

Comment: Might be something to do with Windows-style linebreaks (`\r\n`) vs Unix-style linebreaks (`\n`). Hard to tell given how vague the question is.

Comment: how are you uploading them? how are you editing them, you know the difference with line breaks between os's?

Comment: I'm working on windows environment and the hosting is unix however this is not happening every time. but most often. if there is two line breaks in original file then it add one another. so three line breaks when i try to edit it back. I'm using filezilla to upload my files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using FileZilla, try going to `Edit -> Settings -> Transfers -> File Types` and set `Default transfer type` to `Binary`. That should stop whatever line ending conversions are going on.

As an aside, in my experience, this sort of problem occurs most commonly when a single line ending convention is not applied consistently within the same file. Then the software detects one convention (e.g., the one used towards the beginning of the file), and applies the conversion blindly across the rest of the file.